# Win32 Runtime Created LISTBOX and LB_ADDSTRING errors

Tags: c, winapi, listbox, c89

I am creating a LISTBOX using the default LISTBOX class in Windows and the C language.
The Listbox is drawn onto the main window properly, but when I try to subsequently fill it with any data, it silently fails. `SendMessage()` returns 0 every time. The handle to the listbox has been confirmed to be proper, the `LB_ADDSTRING` definition is `0x0180` (which I assume is also proper).
I have tried `char *` and `wchar_t *` and literal strings, none of them will show up, all of them return 0 from `SendMessage()` calls no matter how many times it is called. I am left to assume that perhaps my message handler, or my class and window creation, are incorrect. Here is the most recent version of the associated code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DBWinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch ( uMsg )
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void DBClassBuilder()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DBWinProc;
    wc.hInstance = g_pi.hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("LISTBOX");

    if ( !RegisterClassEx(&wc) )
        return;

    g_pi.hb.hDBListBox = CreateWindowEx(
        0, TEXT("LISTBOX"),
        TEXT(""),
        WS_CHILD | LBS_HASSTRINGS | LBS_STANDARD,
        0, 0, 100, 300,
        g_pi.hWnd, NULL, g_pi.hInstance, NULL);

    if ( g_pi.hb.hDBListBox == NULL )
        return;

    SendMessage(g_pi.hb.hDBListBox, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));

    ShowWindow(g_pi.hb.hDBListBox, g_pi.nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(g_pi.hb.hDBListBox);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    g_pi.hWnd = hWnd;
    switch ( uMsg )
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            SaveMainPos();
            DBClassBuilder();
            SendMessage(g_pi.hb.hDBListBox, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)"test");
            break;
        case WM_PAINT:
            SaveMainPos();
            UpdateChildren();
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried so use  `SendMessage` after the Window has been created? After `UpdateWindow()`?

Comment: I originally had SendMessage() being called in the DBWinProc() WM_CREATE section. I thought that may have been part of the problem, but no matter where I moved the call, it still produced the same result. MSDN states that the SendMessage() call should return the index of where the item was added. So, I am unsure why it does not return LB_ERR or the like, yet also does not display the item, and no matter how many times SendMessage() is called the return is always 0.

Comment: As a quick test, I copy/pasted the SendMessage() call right after the UpdateWindow() call in DBCLassBuilder() and it returned 0 without adding the item to the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you register a "LISTBOX" class yourself, your window is of that class instead of the standard listbox control class. Therefore the standard listbox window procedure is never called.

What you probably want to achieve is called subclassing, using an existing windowclass and tweaking the behavior. A web search should give you many examples of proper subclassing.

Comment: I was afraid that may be what was happening. I was unsure how to determine that for myself. Thank you for the clarification. I will look further into subclassing to see if it is actually what I am wanting. I take it that if it turns out I just want a standard one that I should just call CreateWindowEx() without a custom WNDCLASSEX struct being passed?

Comment: yes, to get the standard one, you don't need to RegisterWindowClass[Ex], you can just use the standard class name in CreateWindow[Ex]